# No output received for subscriber program

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running ROS melodic on my Ubuntu Bionic. I have coded a publisher and subcriber program. While the publisher program works correctly, when I run the subscriber program using `rosrun` I dont receive any output

The publisher code -

```
//This program publishes randomly generated velocity messages for the turtlesim//

#include<ros/ros.h>
#include<geometry_msgs/Twist.h>
#include<stdlib.h>      //For rand and RAND_MAX

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    //Initialize ROS system and publish a node
    ros::init(argc, argv, "publish_velocity");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    
    //Create publisher object
    ros::Publisher pub = nh.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("turtle1/cmd_vel", 1000);

    //Seed the random number generator
    srand(time(0));

    //Loop at 2Hz until the node is shut down
    ros::Rate rate(2);
    while(ros::ok()){
        //Create and fill in the four fields, the other four fields, which are ignored by turtlesim, default to 0
        geometry_msgs::Twist msg;
        msg.linear.x = double(rand())/double(RAND_MAX);
        msg.angular.z = 2*double(rand())/double(RAND_MAX) - 1;

        //Publish the message
        pub.publish(msg);

        //Send a message to rosout with the details
        ROS_INFO_STREAM("Sending random velocity command:"
        <<" linear="<<msg.linear.x
        <<" angular="<<msg.angular.z);

        //Wait until its time for another iteration
        rate.sleep();

    }
}
```

and the corresponding subscriber code -

```
//This program subscribes to /turtle1/pose and displays it on the screen

#include<ros/ros.h>
#include<turtlesim/Pose.h>
#include<iomanip> //for std::setprecision and std::fixed

// A calback function that is executed each time a pose message is received
void poseMessageReceived(const turtlesim::Pose &msg){
    ROS_INFO_STREAM(std::setprecision(2) << std::fixed
    << "position=("<< msg.x <<","<< msg.y<< ")"
    << " direction="<< msg.theta);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    //Initialize a ROS system and become a node
    ros::init(argc, argv, "subscribe_to_pose");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;

    //Create a subscriber object
    ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe("turle1/pose", 1000, &poseMessageReceived);

    //Let ROS take over
    ros::spin();
}
```

Both of these have been saved under the same package. The CMakeLists.txt is-

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(first_package)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp geometry_msgs turtlesim)
catkin_package()
include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(hello hello.cpp)
add_executable(pubvel pubvel.cpp)
add_executable(subpose subpose.cpp)
target_link_libraries(hello ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(pubvel ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(subpose ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

What could be possible error here. It compiles perfectly when i use `catkin_make`. Is the error in the code itself or in the CMakeLists.txt?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/312768/no-output-received-for-subscriber-program/) by [TristanNoctis](https://answers.ros.org/users/39423/tristannoctis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 29 on 2019-01-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-15**:
I'm sorry to be so strict, but I'm closing your question as it doesn't follow the [Support Guidelines](http://wiki.ros.org/Support). Specifically the sections about **not** using screenshots to show consoles, log files and/or code (snippets).

Please edit your question and I'll re-open it.

**Comment by [TristanNoctis](https://answers.ros.org/users/39423/tristannoctis/) on 2019-01-15**:
Sorry for posting the screenshot. Will i be able to post just the code like i have done for the CMakeLists.txt? Even though the topics do not match, the by publishing random values to the command velocity, the pose of the turtle changes and hence I should get a output for the subscriber right?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-15**:\

> Will i be able to post just the code like i have done for the CMakeLists.txt?

yes. It's all text.

**Comment by [TristanNoctis](https://answers.ros.org/users/39423/tristannoctis/) on 2019-01-15**:
Ok I have done it. Can you please open the question and solve it?

**Comment by [curi_ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/37504/curi_ros/) on 2019-01-15**:
What is it that you want to achieve? Do you want the bot to update its pose based on the given command velocities? Are you doing this on hardware or in simulation?

**Comment by [TristanNoctis](https://answers.ros.org/users/39423/tristannoctis/) on 2019-01-15**:
I am doing it on simulation. Based on the command velocities being sent, the turtle pose would change right? I want this pose to be given as output and displayed by the subscriber.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You've misspelled the topic in your subscriber. You're listening on a topic that doesn't exist.

---

Originally posted by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) with karma: 1850 on 2019-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TristanNoctis](https://answers.ros.org/users/39423/tristannoctis/) on 2019-01-16**:
where exactly is this error?

**Comment by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) on 2019-01-16**:
Not the response I was expecting, but here you go.

//Create a subscriber object
ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe("turle1/pose", 1000, &poseMessageReceived);

**Comment by [TristanNoctis](https://answers.ros.org/users/39423/tristannoctis/) on 2019-01-16**:
Oh sorry I am new to both programming and ROS. By the way, how could this have compiled even though made is mistake?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-16**:
@TristanNoctis: topic names are not checked by the compiler, it's just a string.

It would also be interesting to think about how that could be checked at compile time: how would the compiler know which topics exist at runtime, when topics can be created at runtime?

**Comment by [TristanNoctis](https://answers.ros.org/users/39423/tristannoctis/) on 2019-01-16**:
I get it now! But still after making the changes, I dont see any output. Is there any other change i must do?

**Comment by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) on 2019-01-16**:
You can echo the topic you're listening to to make sure the publisher is actually publishing. That narrows down the issue by 50%. Also when needed I have nodes print stuff to screen so I can track how far through the processing it gets before things stop working.

**Comment by [TristanNoctis](https://answers.ros.org/users/39423/tristannoctis/) on 2019-01-18**:
@billy: can you elaborate? I am printing the pose.

**Comment by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) on 2019-01-18**:
Who is publishing the pose topic? It's not your publisher.

I have to ask. After you corrected the name of the topic, did you rerun catkin_make and restart roscore? Put a few very simple info_stream statements in your main to make sure the program is even starting.

**Comment by [TristanNoctis](https://answers.ros.org/users/39423/tristannoctis/) on 2019-01-19**:
@billy: Yes it seems restarting the roscore was all that I needed to do. Thanks for your help!

**Comment by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) on 2019-01-19**:
Thank you for responding. Too many people ask for help and then never come back to update or say thanks.

**Comment by [TristanNoctis](https://answers.ros.org/users/39423/tristannoctis/) on 2019-01-20**:
Hmm idk. The reason I ask a question is because I want it to be solved. I dont get why someone would not respond after you have answered them.